# Can we typecast buffer into C++ structure on client when server is sending data as c structure?

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets

I have server, client processes written in C named as NetworkServer.c and NetworkClient.c and these 2 are communicating using linux sockets. When client sends a request as below to get ethernet statistics,

```
// rxbuf - character array of 128K
// ETHERNET_DIAGNOSTIC_INFO - structure typedefed
recv(sockfd, rxbuf, sizeof(ETHERNET_DIAGNOSTIC_INFO), 0)
```

server fills the data in to rxbuf (as ETHERNET_DIAGNOSTIC_INFO because server also uses the same copy of header file where this structure is defined) and sends the data. Once client receives, it will typecast as below to get the data.

```
ETHERNET_DIAGNOSTIC_INFO *info = (ETHERNET_DIAGNOSTIC_INFO *) rxbuf;
```

the structure is defined in NetworkDiag.h as below.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct ETHERNET_DIAGNOSTIC_INFO
{
    uint32_t             cmdId; 
    unsigned long        RxCount[MAX_SAMPLES];
    unsigned long        TxCount[MAX_SAMPLES];
    time_t               TimeStamp[MAX_SAMPLES] ;
    char                 LanIpAddress[20];
    char                 LanMacAddress[20];
    char                 WanIpAddress[20];
    char                 LanDefaultGateway[20];
    char                 LanSubnetMask[20];
    char                 LanLease[5000];
}ETHERNET_DIAGNOSTIC_INFO;
```

This is working fine.

Now there is a requirement that I need to create a c++ file which should work as client (I removed client C file and server should remain as c file). I defined header file for the structure definition as below.

```
struct ETHERNET_DIAGNOSTIC_INFO
{
    uint32_t             cmdId; 
    unsigned long        RxCount[MAX_SAMPLES];
    unsigned long        TxCount[MAX_SAMPLES];
    time_t               TimeStamp[MAX_SAMPLES] ;
    char                 LanIpAddress[20];
    char                 LanMacAddress[20];
    char                 WanIpAddress[20];
    char                 LanDefaultGateway[20];
    char                 LanSubnetMask[20];
    char                 LanLease[5000];
};
```

basically I removed the C++ guard and typedef and using the below code in client.cpp file to get the result from server.

```
if(recv(sockfd, rxbuf, sizeof(ETHERNET_DIAGNOSTIC_INFO), 0) > 0)
{
    ETHERNET_DIAGNOSTIC_INFO *info = reinterpret_cast<ETHERNET_DIAGNOSTIC_INFO *> (rxbuf);
}
```

I am not getting the correct results. The values in the structure are misplaced (some values are correct but lot of values are misplaced). I tried 'C' type casting also but no use.

I doubt that we can not typecast buffer into C++ structure on client when server is sending data as c structure. Is it correct? Can any one please let me know how to solve this issue?

Comment: It may be useful to write a C function to receive and cast that pointer  (as you have), and compile it into its own .o file.  Then use your C++ to cast the pointer, and also call your C function.  Link everything.  Set a breakpoint in the C, so that when it hits, both your C++ and C code are interpreting the same data at the same time.  It could provide a clue as to what's going wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that the client and server machines will be running the same version of the same o/s and will have the same hardware type?  If not, you probably need to use a portable mechanism for encoding the data (but if it is a school project, you may be able to get away with the assumption).  The troubles include 'what if one machine is big-endian and the other little-endian?', and 'what if the machines have different sizes for some of the types?', and 'what if the new version of the o/s has different fields compared to the old version?'.  There are other possible problems too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes, Client and server are both using same version, same OS and running on same box.

Comment: 2 things to consider:
Are your C and C++ compilers packing the structures the same? Try a `sizeof(ETHERNET_DIAGNOSTIC_INFO)` on both sides of the link, and make sure they match.
Are your C and C++ compilers treating the types as the same size? `unsigned long` on your server might have a different size than your client. Creates great fun when serializing/deserializing values coming from a non-x86 architecture.

Comment: "I removed the C++ guard". Why?

Comment: @kadina: that simplifies things magnificently; it allows you to ignore the possible problems I postulated.

Comment: "Yes, Client and server are both using same version". Of what? One is using a C compiler and the other is using a C++ compiler.

Comment: @n.m. - I added C++ guard. But result remains the same.

Comment: Even if running ont the same platform, using proper serialization and a well-defined format will avoid many future problems. Just think if you recompile one or decide to use the software on different machines or use a proper class in C++ for the object data. For most applications, the overhead is negligible, including many (modern) embedded platforms. Note that you should use at least `stdint.h` types throughout the fields.

Comment: Even if they are running on the same box, they may not be compatible because of different compiler options.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are multiple problems with this approach:

1. [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) might be different between server and client machine

   You then need to deserealize numbers and `time_t`'s.
2. [Structure packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) might be different between code compiled on server (c++) and on client (C)

   You then need to use a protocol to send data, like binary ASN, protobuf or many others.
3. `if(recv(sockfd, rxbuf, sizeof(ETHERNET_DIAGNOSTIC_INFO), 0) > 0)`
   there is no guarantee `recv` will read exactly `sizeof(ETHERNET_DIAGNOSTIC_INFO)` bytes.

   You need to wrap this into `while` loop (**code is sample and might be non-compilable**):

.

```
int left = sizeof(ETHERNET_DIAGNOSTIC_INFO);
char *ptr = rxbuf;
int rd;

while(left>0)
{
    rd=recv(sockfd, ptr, left, 0);
    if(rd==0)
    {
        if(left>0) return SOCKET_CLOSED_PREMATURELY;
        else return SOCKET_DONE;
    } else if(rd==-1 && errno==EAGAIN) {
        //do again
        continue; 
    } else if(rd==-1 && errno!=EAGAIN) {
       return SOCKET_ERROR;
    }
    left = left - rd;
    ptr=ptr+rd;
}
```

The proper way to send binary data is to use protobuf or apache thrift, or ASN or invent something yourself.

Comment: I inevitably end up writing a `recv_exact()` function that does this loop generically.

Comment: Especially consider the advice here that recommends using ASN or [protobuf](https://github.com/google/protobuf). You don't really want to marshal `struct`s directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably do it but are likely to run into serious significant issues in trying:

- Different compilers and compiler settings will pack and align structures differently in order to optimise for the particular processor architecture.  There is absolutely no guarantee that the members of a structure will lay out exactly next to each other unless you play with pragmas.
- Different processors will use different byte orders for things like integers and floating point values.  If you are going to exchange data between a client and server (or vice versa) it behooves you to explicitly define the byte order and then make both sides conform to that definition regardless of the native order.
- Values like unsigned long will have different sizes based upon the processor architecture targeted by the compiler.  In order to reliably exchange data, you will need to explicitly define the size of the values that will be transferred.

For these reasons, I prefer to write functions (or methods) that will explicitly pack and unpack messages as they are exchanged.  By doing so, you will be subjected to much fewer seemingly mysterious errors.

Answer (score 1):

A number of possible explanations spring to mind:

- Different packing of `ETHERNET_DIAGNOSTIC_INFO` between a C `struct` and a C++ `struct`.
- (less likely) Different alignments of `rxbuf` (you don't show where this pointer comes from). There are no guarantees in C or C++ that reading a `int` or `long` that does not lie on natural boundary (e.g. 4-byte aligned) yields correct results.
- That your C and C++ compilers are compiling against different ABIs (e.g. 32-bit and 64-bit respectively).  Note that `sizeof(time_t) == 4` on a 32-bit platform and `8` on many 64-bit platforms.

All of these issues point in the same direction: Mapping a `struct` onto a wire data layout like this is really non-portable and problematic.

If you really insist on doing it you'll need to do the following:

- Use `#pragma pack` directives (or better: if using a C++11 compiler `__attribute__ ((__packed__)))`. Even then, you can get surprises.
- Decide which byte-ordering you intend using and byte-swap all multi-byte values with `htons()` and friends. The convention is for multi-byte quantities to be big-endian over TCP/IP.
- Ensure the buffer you call `recv()` with is aligned - probably to a 4-byte boundary.

A more robust approach is to read the input buffer as a stream of bytes, reconstructing any multi-byte fields as required.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can as the buffer is just the byte representation of the struct sent by the other side. After you have handled the byte order, you can just cast the buffer pointer to a pointer of the type of your struct.

In C++ you can write for example `ETHERNET_DIAGNOSTIC_INFO* NewPtr = reinterpret_cast<ETHERNET_DIAGNOSTIC_INFO*>(buffer);`
This will do what you want unless you run an older C++ compiler not capable of understanding C++11 syntax. However, depending on your compiler the error might arrive from padding the data.

If you define bit fields and pack the struct on both sides you will be fine though. Ask if you need help, but google is your friend.

> > I doubt that we can not typecast buffer into C++ structure on client when server is sending data as c structure. Is it correct?

EDIT:
You can cast any binary data generated by any programming language into a readable piece of code in your program. After all, it is all about bits and bytes. So you can cast any data from any program to any data in any other program. Could you quickly print the sizeof(ETHERNET_DIAGNOSTIC_INFO) on both sides and see if they match?

Comment: I did read the question quickly, but I believe he said he tried this and it is not working.  He also seeks to know why it is not working.

Comment: Yes. I tried and it is not working and also reinterpret_cast should be as below. ETHERNET_DIAGNOSTIC_INFO* NewPtr = reinterpret_cast<ETHERNET_DIAGNOSTIC_INFO *>(buffer)

Comment: Sorry, you've overlooked just too many things that [fukanchik mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32618763/119527) which are extremely important to consider.

Comment: @kadina Yes, I made a mistake there. Try out the two other things I mentioned. Check the byte order and try packing it with byte fields.

Comment: In general, it's tempting fate to expect the binary representation of structures to be exportable from one build and imported into another build.  Between padding and vtables, byte ordering, and other factors, you can make it happen, but the solution will almost always be brittle and non-portable.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Like what? I mentioned the byte order, I mentioned the packing. The only thing I did not mention was that you might not have received all the data as `recv()` has no guarantee that it will read it all.

Comment: @RussSchultz I would disagree. If you send the data `49, 12, 17, 97, 634, 1` from one device then it will arrive the same way on the receiving end. Making sure that it does end up in that order and with the same number of bytes per value is naturally then assumed performed. I never intended to imply that it would be always easy.

Comment: Yes, bytes can be reliably sent across the wire or written to a file.   The transformation to/from the binary representation and the virtual representation, however, cannot be relied upon unless you do the transformation yourself.  In other words, reading/writing a struct (no matter if you've asked the compiler to "pack" it) will always be fraught with sudden breakage if you rely upon the tools to do something specific if isn't in any specification.

Comment: That is indeed true. However, that is not what he asked for.